# Prove if $\mu$ is a complete measure, and $E_1$, $E_2 - E_1$ are measurable, if $\mu(E_1 \Delta E_2) = 0$, then $E_2$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This question if from Royden's Real Analysis, Section 17.1 problem 5.ii.

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $E_1 \Delta E_2 = (E_1 - E_2) \cup (E_2 - E_1)$.

Prove if $\mu$ is a complete measure, and $E_1$, $E_2 - E_1$ are measurable, if $\mu(E_1 \Delta E_2) = 0$, then $E_2$ is measurable.

Can't this be done by noting that since $E_1 \Delta E_2$ is measurable (with measure $0$), then the complement $(E_1 \Delta E_2)^C$ must be measurable. So writing $$E_2 = (E_2 - E_1) \cup [(E_1 \Delta E_2)^C \cap E_1],$$

we have that $E_2$ is measurable.

Is there something wrong with this proof, as we haven't used that $\mu$ is **complete.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we deal with a complete space, $E_1$ is measurable and $E_1\Delta E_2$ is a $\mu$-nullset then it can be proved that $E_2$ is measurable.

For that the condition that $E_2-E_1$ is measurable is actually redundant.

From $E_2-E_1\subseteq E_1\Delta E_2$ combined with $\mu(E_1\Delta E_2)=0$ it follows directly that $E_2-E_1$ is a $\mu$-nullset. Then the completeness of the space tells us that $E_2-E_1$ is measurable.

Also $E_1\Delta E_2$ is a nullset hence is measurable.

Then we can indeed write $E_2$ as you state in your question showing that it is measurable.

Comment: I see. But if we use the proof I wrote above, then $/mu$ being complete is redundant..?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The expression $\mu(E_1\Delta E_2)=0$ implicity states that $E_1\Delta E_1$ belongs to the domain of $\mu$ which means that this set is measurable. But I must confess also that IMV it is a kind of weird problem.

Comment: "Well done, good and faithful servant"

Comment: @user35687 Thank you for the nice complement:-).